# trying to build a release apk but getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded exception

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, out-of-memory, build.gradle, android-proguard

> Problem : Getting outofmemory error while generating the release apk.
>   error related to "app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease"
>   "org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for
>   task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'"

Solution : 
**Out of memory: Java heap space.
 Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
 For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the 
 maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
*org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m***

Above Solution is working. But is there any efficient way to solve above problem?

Comment: Please add more details about your problem and try to add largeHeap = true in your application tag inside manifest.

Comment: @DheerajRijhwani adding largeHeap cannot possibly help with OOM that happens when **building** application.

Comment: @DheerajRijhwani largeHeap=true is already there. i edited my question and i think solution is also there. Suggestions are welcomed